React Firebase Anonymous authentication
I am trying to add an anonymous authentication functionality in Firebase. When user logs in anonymously, it is also creating an entry in Firebase Realtime Database.
The issue is that when user logs in anonymously, onAuthStateChanged gets triggered immediately, which then triggers fetchCurrentUser before handleAddUserToDb finishes executing. Did I make a mistake?
If I add a delay on fetchCurrentUser then the functions run in the correct order:  handleAddUserToDb then fetchCurrentUser but adding a delay doesn't seem to be best practice...
const handleAnonymousLogin = async () => {
    dispatch({ type: "loading" });

    try {
      const user = await signInAnonymously(auth);

      await handleAddUserToDb(user.user.uid, "Guest", null, null);

      navigate("/home");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error signing in anonymously:", error);
      dispatch({ type: "error" });
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "loading" });

    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const id = user.uid;

        await fetchCurrentUser(id);
      } else {
        dispatch({ type: "logged-out" });
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const fetchCurrentUser = async (uid) => {
    try {
      const userRef = ref(db, `users/${uid}`);
      onValue(userRef, (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          dispatch({ type: "logged-in", payload: snapshot.val() });
        } else {
          alert("User not found.");
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Error fetching user: " + error.message);
    }
  };


Your onValue is based on a callback which does not return a promise, so while the operation is asynchronous, you are not awaiting its result.
As far as I can see, there is no reason to use a realtime listener here though, and you're betting of getting a value once. The latter returns a promise, which means that you can use await on it.
const fetchCurrentUser = async (uid) => {
  try {
    const userRef = ref(db, `users/${uid}`);
    const snapshot = await get(userRef); // 
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      dispatch({ type: "logged-in", payload: snapshot.val() });
    } else {
      alert("User not found.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert("Error fetching user: " + error.message);
  }
};

Because we now use await in fetchCurrentUser, this function will also return a promise, which the makes await that you already have when you call fetchCurrentUser work.

Update: since apparently you want to use both a realtime listener and await the first result, you can return a custom promise from fetchCurrentUser.
The code for that should be something like this:
const fetchCurrentUser = async (uid) => {
  let isFirst = true;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      onValue(userRef, (snapshot) => {
        // If this is the first data we get, resolve the promise so that the await is released
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          if (isFirst) {
            resolve(snapshot.val());
            isFirst = false;
          }
          // For each time we get data, dispatch it to any listeners.
          dispatch({ type: "logged-in", payload: snapshot.val() });
        } else {
          reject("User not found.");
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      reject("Error fetching user: " + error.message);
    }
  });
};


My user object also includes a recipes endpoint, which stores and manages recipe data associated with the user. The reason I am using a realtime listener is to listen to changes to the recipes data when user is adding, editing, or removing recipes so that the updates are being reflected immediately. With get it typically requires a refresh

First off: is it clear from my answer why your current code doesn't work? You're using onValue, which doesn't return a promise. So the await you have when you call fetchUsers doesn't do anything.

If so: you can either modify your code to return a custom promise for the first time you get a value in the onValue callback, or you can split the two parts. Use get to get the profile initially when the user signs in, and only then use onValue afterwards to listen for updates.

I added an example of return a custom promise to my answer too.

I tried the example of returning a custom promise, and it doesn't seem to fix the issue as fetchCurrentUser still runs before handleAddUsersToDb finishes executing. However, I decided to go with the second approach of splitting it into two parts which solves my problem. Thanks!
